# Laravel 5 - polymorphism comments table with conditions

Tags: model, polymorphism, laravel-5

In my program a user can comment on a news and on a match.

```
Comment table:

id - (primary)
comment_type - (1 =  match, 2 = news)
comment_id (The id to the type. News.id or match.id)
profile_id
text
```

I have a problem with the relationship because the comment table can store both news comments and match comments, and I do not have foreign key because of that.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
Comment model

 public function comment()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

News model

public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'comment');
    }
```

I would like the comments to be in one table instead of a match_comment and news_comment table.

When I call $news->comments, it returns a empty array.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use Laravel's built-in polymorphic relations support with a database structure that doesn't support it. The [relevant section of the manual](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) says something like this (tweaked a bit for your scenario):

> The key fields to notice here are the [commentable_id] and [commentable_type] on the comments table. The ID will contain the ID value of, in this example, the owning [match] or [news], while the type will contain the **class name** of the owning model [i.e. not an integer like 1 = match and 2 = news]. This is what allows the ORM to determine which type of owning model to return when accessing the [commentable] relation.

I'm not sure you're going to be able to bend this to work with your given table structure. You should probably change it if you can - or you may need to stick with custom queries or convenience methods on your models for accessing this data.

So, to answer your actual question, I believe you are ultimately getting an empty result for `$news->comments` because the query being run behind the scenes is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE comment_id = {$news->id} AND comment_type = 'App\News';
```

**EDIT**

According to the example structure in the docs, you would probably want a table structure along the lines of:

```
news
    id - integer
    other columns...      

matches
    id - integer
    other columns...

comments
    id - integer
    text - string
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

You'd then also need to tweak your News and Match classes to have:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Comments', 'commentable');
}
```

Notice the **commentable** parameter refers to a method that should be on the Comment class:

```
class Comment extends Model {

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

(significant because you have indicated that you are currently using `comment()` as the method name)

Comment: I see the problem, but do you have an example to how my table structure should be?

Comment: behic - I think I understand now, instead of a id in comment_type i should have ex. 'App\News'. Is this right?

Comment: @AndreasBaran - Yes, I've made an edit to clarify and tried to keep it as much in line with the laravel docs as possible.